# Unable to compress into volumes with 7zip

Tags: command-line, compression, 7-zip

I'm trying to compress some files into a 7Z split archive from the command line. But when I run the following command:

```
7z.exe a -t7z myarchive.7z *.dat -v250m
```

I get the message 'Not implemented!'. It seems to work when I switch to -tzip (and .zip) instead of -t7z. Any ideas as to what the problem is? Btw, I'm running v9.20.

Comment: In [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z#Limitations) it is implied in the last sentence that the 7z archive format does not support it, though this is not stated explicitly. If you must use 7z format your only option is to create a single archive and use a file splitter; the file segments will need to be recombined before the archive can be accessed.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the answer. Looks like I'll just be sticking to the plain zip format then.

Comment: ... or RAR. This seems to be the most used format these days for split archives.

Comment: Did you run that command multiple times in a row? Because on my machine it worked the first time but not the second. After deleting the resulting .001 etc files from the first run it worked again. So I assume the thing that is "Not implemented" is the updating of split archives. Because the `7z a` command is also used to update files in an existing archive. Sorry to dig this old question up again.

Comment: actually the split 7zip archive does not need to be recombined before the archive can be accessed, provided all files are in the same folder; you can simply say something like 7z l myarchive.7z.001